# Playn. Android build failure in eclipse

Tags: playn

I'm trying to start developing games using playn, but I can't get a working setup on my laptop. I've tried multiple installation guides etc. but I end up with the same error in eclipse:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] funktest Metaproject
[INFO] funktest Core
[INFO] funktest Java
[INFO] funktest HTML
[INFO] funktest Android
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building funktest Metaproject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ andre ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ andre ---
[INFO] Installing /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/pom.xml to /home/torgeir/.m2/repository/com/torgeirsandre/andre/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/andre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building funktest Core 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ andre-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ andre-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/core/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:compile (default-compile) @ andre-core ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ andre-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/core/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ andre-core ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test (default-test) @ andre-core ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/core/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ andre-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ andre-core ---
[INFO] Installing /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/core/target/andre-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/torgeir/.m2/repository/com/torgeirsandre/andre-core/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/andre-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/core/pom.xml to /home/torgeir/.m2/repository/com/torgeirsandre/andre-core/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/andre-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building funktest Java 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ andre-java ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ andre-java ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/java/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:compile (default-compile) @ andre-java ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ andre-java ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/java/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ andre-java ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test (default-test) @ andre-java ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/java/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ andre-java ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ andre-java ---
[INFO] Installing /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/java/target/andre-java-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/torgeir/.m2/repository/com/torgeirsandre/andre-java/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/andre-java-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/java/pom.xml to /home/torgeir/.m2/repository/com/torgeirsandre/andre-java/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/andre-java-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building funktest HTML 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ andre-html ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ andre-html ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/html/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:compile (default-compile) @ andre-html ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ andre-html ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/html/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ andre-html ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test (default-test) @ andre-html ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/html/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile (default) @ andre-html ---
[INFO] com.torgeirsandre.andre.funktest is up to date. GWT compilation skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ andre-html ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [andre-html] in [/home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/html/target/andre-html-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/html/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [527 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/html/target/andre-html-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ andre-html ---
[INFO] Installing /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/html/target/andre-html-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /home/torgeir/.m2/repository/com/torgeirsandre/andre-html/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/andre-html-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing /home/torgeir/playn/workspace/andre/html/pom.xml to /home/torgeir/.m2/repository/com/torgeirsandre/andre-html/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/andre-html-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building funktest Android 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ andre-android ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] funktest Metaproject .............................. SUCCESS [0.531s]
[INFO] funktest Core ..................................... SUCCESS [1.340s]
[INFO] funktest Java ..................................... SUCCESS [0.392s]
[INFO] funktest HTML ..................................... SUCCESS [4.900s]
[INFO] funktest Android .................................. FAILURE [0.145s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.703s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 26 16:12:06 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/288M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-13:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project andre-android: The plugin com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-13 requires Maven version [3.0.3,) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginIncompatibleException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :andre-android
```

I have tried multiples versions of maven like 2.2.1, 2.0.11, 3.0.4

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or maybe knows a good way to install everything
from scratch and get a working playn setup?

Regards,
Torgeir

Answer (score 2):

Don't build the Android deployment of your game via Eclipse. Use Eclipse to develop and test your game and then when the time comes to deploy your game to an Android device for testing, take a brief detour to the dreaded command line and invoke the following commands:

```
cd funktest
mvn package
cd android
mvn android:deploy
```

Your life will be vastly simpler if you don't try to route every last minute aspect of your project development through Eclipse.

Also, be sure that the Maven that runs from your command line is Maven 3.0.3 or greater, as the error you are seeing above is specifically related to using an old version of Maven:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-13:generate-sources
>   (default-generate-sources) on project andre-android: **The plugin
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-13
>   requires Maven version [3.0.3,)** -> [Help 1]

You can check which version of Maven you are running on the command line by invoking `mvn -v`. It will report something like:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 09:31:09-0800)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.3/libexec
Java version: 1.6.0_29, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll just ignore the error for now and run my games with ant until I'm ready to publish/testing on android:) entering 'mvn -v' showed Apache Maven 3.0.4 but after a reboot it says that maven isn't installed:S

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.  I solved it by going to Tools -> Plugins -> Installed tab -> Select Groovy -> Activate button -> Close button.

After this you may get another error saying API level 11 is not installed.  If you do you'll have to go to Tools -> Android SDK and AVD Manager -> check and install Android 3.0 (API 11).

Comment: And why did you have to do that?